# HTML fixed position tables

Tags: html, css

I have multiple tables stacked on top of each other, each have the same amount of columns which can be anywhere up to 50+.  With this many columns as you can expect, you need to scroll left and right on the page in order to see all the data.

Now, my problem is.. I want to leave the first table in a fixed position so that if I were to scroll up and down on the page it would always be visible.  And at the same time if I scroll left and right the fixed table will also scroll left and right.

I have researched multiple ways people were handling their tables.  Such as creating a duplicate table underneath the table you want fixed (in order to keep all the data position correctly) and then using `position: absolute`, to freeze the table in place.  Seems that this method would be perfect if my table's x-axis didnt expand off the screen.

Comment: Why can't you just use position fixed? It will be fixed on the screen no matter which way you scroll.

Comment: Thats my problem, I only want it to be fixed when i scroll up and down.  I dont want it to be fixed when I scroll left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to take a look at [dataTables.net](https://datatables.net) - their tool provides heaps of options including fixed scrolling. It may be an option for you. Here's one of [their examples](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedHeader/top_bottom_left_right.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your situation correctly, I think you'll need a little bit of Javascript to make it work.  The good news is that there's a nifty, ready made tool you can use.

Check out this demo to see if the functionality is what you're looking for:  (They're using small boxes rather than tables for the demo, but you'll get the idea.)
http://demo.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/

If that looks like what you want, here are the instructions:

http://www.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/